# Right way to delete comments on the deletion of a post in a social media application using cosmos db

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have a social media application that uses cosmos DB (SQL API) [.net client, using the cosmos-client sdk]. I have followed the design pattern similar to what's described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/social-media-apps.

So, I have one container that holds all posts and another holding all comments. They are all parented by virtue of their id properties. They look something like this:

```
Posts Container {
    id: ...
    userid: ... (partition key)
    ...
}

Comments Container {
    id: ...
    postid: ... (partition key)
    ...
}
```

My issue comes when it is time to delete a post. When a user deletes a post, I can go and delete the corresponding object from the 'posts' container using its id. But now to delete all the comments that were associated with that post, I have to individually delete them in a loop, as from what I understand, cosmos SQL API doesn't let you bulk delete items even in the same partition key. Considering each delete takes us around 6 RUs, if I have a post with 500 comments, my understanding is that by deleting them individually, it would cost us 6 * 500 = 3000 RUs just to delete one post. That doesn't seem very feasible. I also don't want the comments to just be sitting there without a parent.

One workaround I have thought of is that I could structure the comments container something like this:

```
Comments Container {
    id:
    postid:
    comments: [
        {
            commentid: ...
            ...
        }
        {
            commentid: ...
            ...
        }
    ]
}
```

Doing this would easily let me delete the whole comment object upon deleting a post as it now becomes a single delete operation when a post gets deleted. But doing this breaks the fundamental idea of breaking down the comments and posts into different containers and each into a separate object of its own and without a parent object as operations on a particular object in this parented set costs more.

What I mean is, from what I understand, with an above structure, if I have to update the number of likes, or just delete one individual comment, that cost is much larger, and I expect the latter use case to be much more than posts getting deleted.

Am I approaching this scenario in the wrong way? Are there any tricks in cosmos I can use to do this more efficiently?

P.S. My application currently has some users so any changes will also require me to be able to migrate the data to a new structure (if needed) efficiently.

P.P.S. I have seen how to delete data using stored proc, but considering the stored proc internally deletes one by one, I'm assuming the RU consumption would be the same.

Comment: What about just treating the post and it's comments as a single document? i.e. keeping the comments for a post within the respective post document. Then when you delete the post, the comments go with it

Comment: There's no "right" answer, but... With your proposed alternative, you're introducing an "unbounded array" situation - if you ever have enough comments that you exceed max document size, your app fundamentally breaks. Same basic issue happens when trying to create a single document containing post+comments (per @devNull's suggestion). FYI 3000 RU isn't a high cost if done infrequently. Or maybe it's cheaper, RU-wise, to set a TTL for comment documents when the parent is deleted? Or set a `deleted` flag and run a nightly cleanup?

Comment: @devNull Taken from the link I posted above: Cosmos DB has a document size limit, and reading/writing large documents can impact the scalability of your application.

If I embed comments inside the post object, since I can have infinitely many comments per post, this is not very scalable.

Comment: @DavidMakogon I have seen the TTL delete option, but I didn't know I could set TTL based delete 'after' my parent document has been deleted. How can I do this? Could you share a link to reference?

Comment: @ArvindSasikumar did you find a way to do this? the only way i can think of is a nightly job (or when traffic is low) task to delete all comments for deleted posts.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so as of version `3.25.0` you can use `DeleteAllItemsByPartitionKeyStreamAsync` (in preview) to delete multiple items in bulk. Will likely require a bit of architectural changes (single containers probably).

More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/how-to-delete-by-partition-key?tabs=dotnet-example#feature-overview)